# How to index the plugin field in nutch with solr?

Tags: solr, nutch

I integrate nutch/solr/hbase to construct a search engine, it work well, except that some fileds in the schma.xml are not indexed to solr.
The schema.xml likes this:

```
<schema name="nutch" version="1.5">
    <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"
        omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0"
        omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0"
        omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0"
        omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
      <fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- core fields -->
    <field name="batchId" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="digest" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="false"/>

    <!-- fields for index-basic plugin -->
    <field name="host" type="url" stored="false" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="url" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true"
        required="true"/>
    <field name="content" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="cache" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="tstamp" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <!-- fields for index-anchor plugin -->
    <field name="anchor" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for index-more plugin -->
    <field name="type" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="contentLength" type="long" stored="true"
        indexed="true"/>
    <field name="lastModified" type="date" stored="true"
        indexed="true"/>
    <field name="date" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for languageidentifier plugin -->
    <field name="lang" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for subcollection plugin -->
    <field name="subcollection" type="string" stored="true"
        indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for feed plugin (tag is also used by microformats-reltag)-->
    <field name="author" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="tag" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="feed" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="publishedDate" type="date" stored="true"
        indexed="true"/>
    <field name="updatedDate" type="date" stored="true"
        indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for creativecommons plugin -->
    <field name="cc" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for tld plugin -->
    <field name="tld" type="string" stored="false" indexed="false"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>content</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

The fields in " -- core fields --" and "-- fields for index-basic plugin --" are indexed to solr, but other fields, such as the fields in "-- fields for index-anchor plugin --"  -- fields for index-more plugin -- , are not.

what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to activate those plugins in your nutch-default or nutch-site file.

```
<property>
 <name>plugin.includes</name>
 <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor|more)|scoring- opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
```

Then you might want to add them in the solrindex-mapping.xml file as well...

```
<fields>
 <field dest="content" source="content"/>
 <field dest="title" source="title"/>
 <field dest="host" source="host"/>
 <field dest="segment" source="segment"/>
 <field dest="boost" source="boost"/>
 <field dest="digest" source="digest"/>
 <field dest="tstamp" source="tstamp"/>
 <field dest="anchor" source="anchor"/>
 <field dest="type" source="type"/>
 <field dest="id" source="url"/>
 <copyField source="url" dest="url"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Compile Nutch and do a new crawl, you should be able to see the index-more and index-anchor fields in solr.

Comment: it works with the first step, but what the solrindex-mapping.xml for? I found this in it:

Comment: If I do not add the fields to olrindex-mapping.xml, the default value of dest and source is identical?

Comment: Yeah the values of solrindex-mapping are useful in case the fields on your Solr schema are different, they are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration in nutch-site.xml or maybe nutch-default.xml in your case

```
<property>
<name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
```